# NodeJS не видит модуль socket.io

Tags: node.js, debian

Здравствуйте. NodeJS  не видит модуль socket.io. Устанавливал так: npm install -g socket.io. Модуль установился в папку /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.

Comment: А зачем вы его глобально устанавливаете?

Comment: А что пишет при запуске скрипта?